# Отнюдь с друг другом несовместимые / не совместимые

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

`Брокколи, зелёная, и брюссельские выродыши, тёмно-бутылочно-зелёные, — это два продукта отнюдь с друг другом несовместимые / не совместимые.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Брокколи, зелёная, и брюссельские выродыши, тёмно-бутылочно-зелёные, — // это два продукта / **отнюдь  друг с другом не совместИмые.***

1. Оба прилагательных есть в словаре, поэтому выбираем форму написания. ***НЕ*** пишется раздельно с прилагательным ***совместимые***, так как частица  ***ОТНЮДЬ*** усиливает отрицание.
2. Определительный оборот **не обособляется,** так как является смысловым центром высказывания (на него падает ударение). С точки зрения грамматики оборот входит в  **именную часть сказуемого.**

[**Вопрос № 238296.**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=238296)    Как правильно говорить: **с друг другом** или друг с другом, к друг другу или друг к другу. Я слышала оба варианта употребления, если правильны оба варианта, то в каких случаях какой употреблять?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка.** В предложных сочетаниях предлоги К, НА, ОТ, С, У и некоторые другие помещаются **после первой части *друг***: *друг с другом, друг к другу.*

**[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109)**

2. **Не обособляются** распространенные определения: <...> 3) связанные по смыслу не только с подлежащим, но и со сказуемым, в состав которого они входят.

**Из словаря**

**СОВМЕСТИМЫЙ,** -ая, -ое; -тим, -а, -о. Такой, который можно совместить с чем-л. С-ые понятия.

**НЕСОВМЕСТИМЫЙ**, -ая, -ое; -тим, -а, -о. Такой, который не может совмещаться, сочетаться, существовать одновременно с кем-, чем-л. другим. Н-ые понятия. Н-ые характеры. Я с нею несовместима. Курение несовместимо со здоровьем. Честь несовместима с подлостью.

Comment: Где говорится о необособлении определительных/деепричастных оборотов только из-за ударения? Почему он только из-за ударения не обособляется?

Comment: @Максим А где говорится, что запятая ставится перед оборотом? Приведите в своём ответе правило, а также ссылку на него, и обратите внимание на то, что запятая ставится далеко не всегда.

Comment: Все исправила и ответила вроде бы?

Answer (score 0):

Возможны оба варианта. Если преобладает отрицание, то раздельно: *не совместимые*; а если утверждение, то слитно: *несовместимые*. Частица *отнюдь* не обязательно усиливает отрицание. А ещë в Вашем примере не хватает запятой:

***Брокколи, зелёная, и брюссельские выродыши, тёмно-бутылочно-зелёные, — это два продукта, отнюдь с друг другом (не)совместимые***.

Эта запятая ставится перед **определительным оборотом**.

Слово *несовместимый* — прилагательное, а не причастие, так что написание подчиняется решению автора, написаннму в начале ответа.